# Terminating thread variable and setting it to NULL

Tags: multithreading, c++builder, tthread

When working with `TThread` descendant I basically have a choice:

- set `FreeOnTerminate` to `true` which deletes my `TThread` descendant object but does not set it to `NULL`
- do it manually and go through all the mess of removing it myself

What I basically need is a way to determine if thread is running so I did the following:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Thread descendant
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TMyThread : public TThread
    {
    private:   UnicodeString StatusLine;  // Used for Synchronize function

               void __fastcall UpdateGUI();
    protected: virtual void __fastcall Execute();
    public:                 __fastcall TMyThread();
    };
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TMyThread *MyThread;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Thread constructor
__fastcall TMyThread::TMyThread() : TThread(true)
{
FreeOnTerminate = false;
Priority        = tpNormal;
}

 // Synchronize function for Form1
void __fastcall TMyThread::UpdateGUI()
{
Form1->Label1 = StatusLine; 
}

// Execute code
void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute()
{
Sleep(2000);
StatusLine = "I am almost done!";
Synchronize(&UpdateGUI);
}

// Thread terminate, delete object, set to NULL
void __fastcall TForm1::ThreadTerminateIfDone(TMyThread *T)
{
if (T != NULL && WaitForSingleObject(reinterpret_cast<void*>(T->Handle),0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
    T->Terminate();
    T->WaitFor();
    delete T;
    T = NULL;
    }
}

// And initialization part which needs to check if thread is already running
void __fastcall TForm1::StartOrRestartThread(TObject *Sender)
{
// Remove old thread if done
ThreadTerminateIfDone(MyThread);

// Check if thread is running - NULL = not running and terminated or uninitialized
if (MyThread == NULL)
    {
    MyThread = new TMyThread();
    MyThread->Start();
    }
else
    {
    Application->MessageBox(L"Thread is still running please wait!", L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

This code works as it is. My questions are:

- is there a way to simplify this? I need to set `MyThread` to NULL after it is done so that the object is not around until next call to start/restart? This cannot be done with `FreeOnTerminate` set to true because it deletes object. I can only try to access object which then generates exception (which I can catch but it is dumb). I really just need to know if MyThread is done with execution before I initialize it or restart it.
- can I restart thread without terminating it (I don't really need to remove object until program finishes) - if I start thread I get "cannot call start on a running or suspended thread" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ThreadTerminateIfDone()` function needs to take the thread pointer by reference, otherwise it will not be able to set pointer to NULL correctly:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ThreadTerminateIfDone(TMyThread* &T)
```

With that said, you can eliminate `ThreadTerminateIfDone()` altogether if you use the thread's `OnTerminate` event to keep track of whether the thread is running.  When `FreeOnTerminate` is set to true, `OnTerminate` is triggered before the thread is freed, eg:

```
class TMyThread : public TThread
{
private:
    String StatusLine;  // Used for Synchronize function
    void __fastcall UpdateGUI();
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall TMyThread();
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern TMyThread *MyThread;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

```
TMyThread *MyThread = NULL;

__fastcall TMyThread::TMyThread()
    : TThread(true)
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
    Priority        = tpNormal;
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::UpdateGUI()
{
    Form1->Label1 = StatusLine; 
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute()
{
    Sleep(2000);
    StatusLine = "I am almost done!";
    Synchronize(&UpdateGUI);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::StartOrRestartThread(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (MyThread == NULL)
    {
        MyThread = new TMyThread();
        MyThread->OnTerminate = ThreadTerminated;
        MyThread->Start();
    }
    else
    {
        Application->MessageBox(L"Thread is still running please wait!", L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyThread = NULL;
}
```

To answer your other question, if you want the thread to be restartable then you have to change the thread design a bit, eg:

```
class TMyThread : public TThread
{
private:
    String StatusLine;  // Used for Synchronize function
    TEvent *RestartEvent;
    void __fastcall UpdateGUI();
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    bool Busy;
    __fastcall TMyThread();
    __fastcall ~TMyThread();
    void __fastcall Restart();
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern TMyThread *MyThread;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

```
TMyThread *MyThread = NULL;

__fastcall TMyThread::TMyThread()
    : TThread(true)
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
    Priority        = tpNormal;
    RestartEvent    = new TEvent(nil, true, true, "");
}

__fastcall TMyThread::~TMyThread()
{
    delete RestartEvent;
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::UpdateGUI()
{
    Form1->Label1 = StatusLine; 
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute()
{
    while (!Terminated)
    {
        if (RestartEvent.WaitFor(1000) == wrSignaled)
        {
            if (Terminated) return;

            RestartEvent.ResetEvent();
            Busy = true;

            StatusLine = "I am doing something!";
            Synchronize(&UpdateGUI);

            Sleep(2000);

            StatusLine = "I am almost done!";
            Synchronize(&UpdateGUI);

            Busy = false;
        }
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::StartOrRestartThread(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (MyThread == NULL)
    {
        MyThread = new TMyThread();
        MyThread->OnTerminate = ThreadTerminated;
        MyThread->Start();
    }
    else if (!MyThread->Busy)
    {
        MyThread->Restart();
    }
    else
    {
        Application->MessageBox(L"Thread is still running please wait!", L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyThread = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I did try this but are you sure I can set MyThread to NULL inside of ThreadTerminated event like that? If the object is not yet freed can it cause access violation?

Comment: @Coder12345: Yes, I am sure. The `OnTerminate` event is triggered via `Synchronize()`, and the thread object will not be freed until after the `OnTerminate` event handler has exited.

Answer (score 1):

Running a while loop in the thread, with some wait at the top to allow it to run once round when signaled, is so preferable to continually creating/terminating/destroying threads, and associated micro-management, that no other course is sane.

Create the thread, put in a while loop with a wait at the top, signal it to run and never terminate the thread at all unless absolutely forced to.

Calls of death:

```
TThread.WaitFor
TThread.Synchronize
TThread.Terminate
```

Try very hard to not use these, ever.

Simple example:

```
TmyThread=class(TThread);
private;
  mySimpleEvent:TSimpleEvent;
public
  constructor create;
  procedure go;
end;

constructor TmyThread.create;
begin
  inherited create(true);
  mySimpleEvent:=TSimpleEvent.Create;
  resume;
end;

procedure TmyThread.go;
begin
  mySimpleEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TmyThread.Execute;
begin
  while mySimpleEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE) do
  begin
    mySimpleEvent.ResetEvent;
    //code to do your stuff
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How am I supposed to update VCL without `Synchronize`? Thread is done in "one-shot" mode so once it finishes it terminates automatically, there is no need for loop. It is OK to avoid create/delete but once terminated I cannot restart it - I get "unable to start suspended or terminated thread". Any ideas?

Comment: Update VCL: PostMessage API.  Thread is done in "one-shot" mode - stop doing "one-shot" mode and use a loop with a synchro object wait at the top: Event or Semaphore.  If you do that, you don't need to terminate the thread and so you don't need to try and restart it - just signal the synchro object and the thread code inside the while loop will be executed again.  Just leave the thread in existence forever, (ie. until the app terminates and the OS kills it anyway).

Comment: So in other words you're suggesting to have thread using 100% of CPU running an empty loop and only do things when signaled to work? I can reduce priority to tpIdle but still would use 100% CPU. Not very CPU friendly. This thread is needed is to connect to server and fetch data maybe once or twice every 15 minutes. It makes no sense to run it in a loop during idle time.

Comment: Nonono!  Wait on a kernel synchro object - thread blocks on it and  CPU use is then 0% until signaled.  Use TEvent.WaitFor, or TSimpleEvent.WaitFfor or WaitForSingleObject() on a semaphore.  No CPU -intensive loop.

Comment: OK, will test it as well. Thanks for good ideas and visible effort you put in.